# Extend a 3rd party function with try/catch

Tags: javascript

I am trying to extend a 3rd party function that uses a try/catch so if there is an error I can log it internally.  I can't seem to extend or prototype the function to log the error, does anyone have an example for this?

```
googletag.cmd.push = function(a) {
    try {
        for (var b = sa(), c = 0; c < arguments.length; ++c) try {
            ea(arguments[c]) && (arguments[c](), this.j++)
        } catch (d) {
            this.l++, b.error(Ta(String(d.message)))
        }
        b.info(Ua(String(this.j), String(this.l)));
        return this.j
    } catch (d) {
        // custom error logging.
        O(1001, d)
    }
}
```

Comment: Is above code your expected result with `O` being your error handler function? What is the initial code?

Comment: the initial code is just the googletag.cmd.push, all the functions in that are internal, I just want to basically extend the catch(d) to save the error to a javascript obj on the page

Comment: So that `push` function is defined by a script you don't control, and you want to be able to call it and detect errors catched inside `push`?

Comment: Have you tried overriding `O`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not feasible purely through javascript.

Easiest solution is to override the function with your custom implementation which would be identical except for logging statements.

If you need to do this for a lot of third party functions I recommend looking into [AST](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstract_syntax_tree) transformation through [codemods](https://github.com/facebook/jscodeshift).

Comment: tried overriding/redefining the function but there seems to be a closure issue with the functions in the googletag.cmd.push scope. ie sa() is undefined

Comment: That is again not something you can tackle using pure javascript. I guess your best bet is to resort to source transformation. As an intermediate measure you may consider making the changes manually and storing the diffs separately in version control so you can apply them through tools like GNU patch to latter versions of the library. If you do so, unless the library makes drastic modifications around the parts changed - you will still be able to go through minor upgrades relatively painlessly.

Comment: got it, that's what I was afraid of.  Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If the function is not suppressing the error and it is bubbling out of the function you should be able to trap it.

```
(function(){
    var originalPush = googletag.cmd.push;
    googletag.cmd.push = function(a){
        try{
            return originalPush(a);
        }catch(e){
            /* logging */
            throw(e);
        }
    }
})()
```

Comment: I think the problem is originalPush has a try/catch so it will never make it into the catch in the overridden function